# Applet - not working because of security.*Exception

Tags: java, security, applet, japplet

The applet to initialise, read and write security tokens show the following Exceptions:

```
com.sun.deploy.security.BlockedException: User has denied the privileges to the code
sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.getProtectionDomain(Unknown Source)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

and

```
User has denied the privileges to the code
```

The code is as follows, the JTextArea is used to show the result.

```
public static void test(final JTextArea textArea) throws Exception {
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
        @Override
        public Object run() {
            try{
                final String label = "Test123";

                textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n\n\t" + Misc.getMethod());
                initializeToken(textArea, label, "123456".toCharArray());

                textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n\n\t\tinit OK");
                writeDataToToken(label, new byte[]{0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f}, "123456".toCharArray());
                textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n\n\t\twrite OK");
                byte[] dataRead = readDataFromToken(label, "123456".toCharArray());
                for (byte i : dataRead) {
                    System.out.println((int) i);
                }
                textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n\n\t\tread OK");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n\n\t\t" + Misc.getStackTrace(e));
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

The following is the applet code in HTML

```
<applet code = 'test.GUI' 

    archive = 'TestApplet.jar, lib/TestLib.jar' 
    width = 700 
    height = 500>

    <resources>
        <nativelib href="nativeLib.dll"/>
    </resources>
    <param name="permissions" value="all-permissions" />
</applet>
```

appletPolicy.txt

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Application-Name: TestApplet
Codebase: https://www.localhost.com:8443/TestApplet.jar
```

...which is then applied to the applet jar TestApplet.jar and resigned using the following:

```
jar ufm dist\TestApplet.jar appletPolicy.txt
jar ufm dist\lib\TestLib.jar appletPolicy.txt

jarsigner dist\TestApplet.jar -keystore web.jks" web -storepass password
jarsigner dist\lib\TestLib.jar -keystore web.jks" web -storepass password
```

How do I get rid of the Exception and make the applet work?

**UPDATE**: there are no problems with File IO operations - the Applet is able to read and write without causing any security Exception, even though the codes for File IO operations are not in the AccessController.doPrivileged() method.

I have also tried signing the nativeLib.dll, but it made no difference.